# how to make extended tables to the existing table by adding existing table columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a existing table with lot of columns .For Example i have a table named patient_data which was created earlier when i start the project with columns everything related to patient like insurances,patient details,appointments etc...which leads to a lot of performance issues on these days as i need to fetch all data from one table.Now i felt to add extended tables as insurance and appointments etc. In these extended tables i want to separate some columns from patient_data table(already existed one).Is it good to implement extended tables and if yes..how can i do it without losing old data and how to add old data to my extended tables from patient_data.

Comment: Are you aware of normalisation? If not research,research,research.

Comment: I have studied normalisation.can i have data loss in normalisation with existing data

Comment: Normalisation would not 'normally' involve data loss.